# How to evade a signature to detect "xp_cmdshell" for SQLi?

Tags: appsec, sql-injection

What methods can be used to bypass a signature which detects "xp_cmdshell"?

Comment: Hi @Bahi - what exactly are you trying to get from this question? It is very sparse on detail. Simple answer is obfuscate the xp_cmdshell string, but what environment, what platform, what are you aiming at?

Comment: Do you have the signatures at hand which are used?

Comment: The signature is matching the exact key word "xp_cmdshell"

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get around a trivial filter that simply checks if the query contains the string "xp_cmdshell"...
and you're dealing with MSSQL...
and you know that xp_cmdshell is active...
and you know that the user has permissions to access xp_cmdshell...
and you need to specifically run xp_cmdshell, e.g. to prove an exploit, or validate the severity of the finding...

you have several options:

1. you can obfuscate the "xp_cmdshell" string, in several ways:
   `DECLARE @s varchar

   SET @s = 'xp_' + 'cmdshell'

   EXEC (@s)`
   Or, you can generate if from charcodes... etc.
2. If what you really want to do is get unrestricted access to the OS, there are other ways besides xp_cmdshell - there are the `sp_OA***` set of procs (to instantiate COM objects), assembly access procs, etc.

Comment: Getting access to COM and assemblies would still require the proper permissions in any case...

Comment: @SteveS correct - but, if the signature is filtering specifically for "xp_cmdshell", COM and assemblies are an easy way to get around that: simply dont call xp_cmdshell...

Comment: Guys I am talking about bypassing a WAF/IPS signature!!

Comment: @Bahi okay, so these are good solutions, no?

Comment: These options will are blocked as well, you cant use these.

Comment: @Bahi, so then your question is not clear. As the original comments on the question noted, there is not enough detail. If the WAF/IDS is only looking for the specific string `"xp_cmdshell"`, neither of these will be caught, since it's not there. Perhaps you can explain better your situation and what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for making this not clear. You are right, the signature wont match the two suggested options. But there are other signatures that will match these suggestions and block the HTTP request. My question is how to by pass the "xp_cmdshell" signature. For example someone suggested using HPP (HTTP Parameter Pollution) to spread the "xp_cmdshell" on two parameters with same name. This did not work. I am looking for way to evade the WAF/IPS to run the SQL query containing xp_cmdshell. Hope this helps

Comment: @Bahi again, the options I gave you would pass a simple string signature. If these are not good enough (did you try them?), you're gonna have to give more info in the question.

Comment: Yes I tried them these are blocked. I tried to explain it as much as I can. Anyway THANKS for the help.

Comment: If these are blocked, then there are other signatures in play here. As I said `a signature which detects "xp_cmdshell"` would not be triggered here... Do you want to tell us what else is blocking?